# NuGet - Is there a way to have package dependency without causing it to be uninstalled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

I have a project (I am the package creator) that has several builds that each depend on MVC (Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc, Microsoft.AspNet.Razor, and Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages). When my package is installed into a brand new MVC project, everything works as expected.

However, when the package is uninstalled, it destroys the project because MVC is inadvertently uninstalled (because it is a dependency), along with all of the dependencies it has. When I try to reinstall those packages, it seems there is no way to get the versions right because (since there is no NuGet log) I have no idea what versions it uninstalled.

My package DOES DEPEND on these libraries being in place, that is, those libraries are referenced directly from my DLL. But I don't want my NuGet package to uninstall them.

Is there a way?

Comment: How are you uninstalling the package in order for it to remove the dependencies? If I uninstall ServiceStack from the Package Manager console it only uninstalls that package and not the packages it depends on. If I uninstall ServiceStack from the Manage Packages dialog it shows a prompt asking if I want to uninstall the dependencies. If I click No it will not uninstall the dependencies. If I click Yes then it will uninstall all the dependencies.

Comment: Hmm...looks like this was fixed in the latest version of NuGet Package Manager version 2.8.50313.31. I guess that is the answer then.